# How do I get twitter posts?

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to get twitter posts following this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPrsVKudecs

there aren't a lot of tutorials regarding this online, and twitters console doesn't support running queries anymore as far as I understood.

any idea why this is happening?

This is the output I get in the Chrome "Network":

```
Remote Address:54.666.666.666:80
Request URL:http://666.com/yh/test/tweets_json.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Response Headers
view source
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 15 Jun 2015 13:51:40 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:666.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Is there a better simple way to do it?

**EDIT:**

tweets_json.php

```
<?php
require 'tmhOAuth.php'; // Get it from: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

// Use the data from http://dev.twitter.com/apps to fill out this info
// notice the slight name difference in the last two items)

$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key' => '',
    'consumer_secret' => '',
    'user_token' => '', //access token
    'user_secret' => '' //access token secret
));

// set up parameters to pass
$parameters = array();

if ($_GET['count']) {
    $parameters['count'] = strip_tags($_GET['count']);
}

if ($_GET['screen_name']) {
    $parameters['screen_name'] = strip_tags($_GET['screen_name']);
}

if ($_GET['twitter_path']) { $twitter_path = $_GET['twitter_path']; }  else {
    $twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
}

$http_code = $connection->request('GET', $connection->url($twitter_path), $parameters );

if ($http_code === 200) { // if everything's good
    $response = strip_tags($connection->response['response']);

    if ($_GET['callback']) { // if we ask for a jsonp callback function
        echo $_GET['callback'],'(', $response,');';
    } else {
        echo $response; 
    }
} else {
    echo "Error ID: ",$http_code, "<br>\n";
    echo "Error: ",$connection->response['error'], "<br>\n";
}

// You may have to download and copy http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

tmhOAuth.php: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/tmhOAuth.php

and this pem key: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

All three in the same folder

In the tutorial it should run the query and get the json output.

I get a blank page.

Comment: Please at least show us the steps and code you're using here; not all of us  are capable or willing to sit through a Youtube tutorial video.

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening?
-> No code... No idea...

Comment: video tutorials make me want to smoke crack...

Comment: I edited my post with the 3 files in my folder. @ShotgunNinja